# Wordpress Shortcode open and close php

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm having trouble adding a shortcode directly to my theme.
The problem occurs with the short code.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

```
[ihc-level-link id=1]
<div id="advc-menu" class="search">
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="s" id="s" value="<?php echo dt_clear($_GET['s']); ?>" autocomplete="off">
        <button class="search-button" type="submit"><span class="icon-search2"></span></button>
    </form>
</div>
[/ihc-level-link]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?php 
    $html = '<div id="advc-menu" class="search">
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="'. esc_url( home_url() ) .'">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="s" id="s" value="'. dt_clear($_GET['s']) .'" autocomplete="off">
        <button class="search-button" type="submit"><span class="icon-search2"></span></button>
    </form>
    </div>';
    echo do_shortcode("[ihc-level-link id=1] ". $html ." [/ihc-level-link id=1]"); 
?>
```